# What underlying semantic notions connect 'sī' to the PIE root *se (to Own, Possess)?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

Preface: [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/si#Fran.C3.A7ais)'s etymology supports U Texas's below, but [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/si#Etymology_8)'s assigns *sī* to a different PIE root: **só*. I am conjecturing that Wiktionary is incorrect.

> [[70% down the page](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1657.html)] *sī* conj if 
>   LRC [Linguistics Research Center, University of Texas, Austin]

I was reading this page on the PIE root **se-* when I noticed the above; why was the 'sī' assigned to the PIE root **se* (to Own, Possess)? I cannot see any semantic notions underlying the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Proto-Indo-European root **se-* is generally taken to have been a reflexive pronominal root meaning "self", i.e. indicating that a word refers to the same thing as some other word (De Vaan 2008, [Philippa e.a. 2003-2009](http://www.etymologiebank.nl/trefwoord/zelf1)). The root **so-* is a different pronominal/demonstrative root that was so far as I know not reflexive. So I would not trust Wiktionary here.

The Latin reflexive pronoun *se* is from Proto-Indo-European **se-* (De Vaan). I wouldn't trust that page from the University of Texas too much: their "own, possess" seems speculative. Perhaps it was based on Pokorny, but I wouldn't depend on it either way.

According to De Vaan, Latin *si* and *sic* are from Proto-Indo-European **so-*, as expected. I don't think there is any doubt about this. It is related to English *so* and many other reflexes.